# loopback "after save" trigger both create and update, but I want update only

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, after-save

```
Product.observe('after save', function(ctx, next){
    productHelper.calProduct(ctx.instance);
    next();
  });
```

I have above method to do something once a product is updated, but 'after save' is also trigger by create. How can I get trigger only by update but not create?

Many thanks!

loopback": "^3.22.0"
"connector": "postgresql"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Remote hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html).

for example:

`Product.afterRemote('updateUser', (ctx, userRes, next) => {
    next()
    {...code ....}
  })`

where `updateUser` is my remote method. Change it with your method name or prototype.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Maybe my question is not very clear. What I really want to do is find out how to  distinguish between a CREATE operation and an UPDATE operation. According to LoopBack 3.x doc, only certain (memory, MongoDB, and MySQL) connectors support ctx.isNewInstance. With other connectors it is undefined. Unfortunately, I am using Postgresql which is not support isNewInstance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out that Postgresql is support isNewInstance, the problem is solved.